# Prevent printing currency unit of MoneyField in django template

Tags: django-templates

I'm using `MoneyField` from `djmoney` app for a field on my model:

```
order_amount = MoneyField(verbose_name=_('Order Amount'), max_digits=9, decimal_places=0, default_currency='IRR')
```

When in `django-template` I want to return a value of my order like below:

```
order.order_amount
```

It prints an additional `Iranian Rial` (ریال) beside of the value. for instance: `100 ریال`

How Can I prevent this leak?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again I find it myself, This time accidentally, I simply used:

```
order.order_amount.amount
```